# SearchBar, how to change text color?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, searchbar

[image: Here's what my search bar looks like]

My search bar has default gray text, but I want it to be white text. I can't figure out how to use swift to change the scope bar text color, and you are unable to do it from storyboard. The closest I've found is

```
searchBarOutlet.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

but alas this won't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its a little hard to access the Textfield inside the UISearchbar.

This is how it works:

```
for subView in self.searchBarOutlet.subviews
    {
        for secondLevelSubview in subView.subviews
        {
            if (secondLevelSubview.isKindOfClass(UITextField))
            {
                if let searchBarTextField:UITextField = secondLevelSubview as? UITextField
                {
                    //set the color here like this:
                    searchBarTextField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Shorter solution:**

```
var textFieldInsideSearchBar = yourSearchbar.valueForKey(“searchField”) as? UITextField 
textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = yourcolor
```

Comment: THANK YOU x100.  Would not have ever figured that out.

Comment: Is that public API? In other words will Apple accept that code when submitting?

Comment: What do you mean with "public API"? Apple doesnt care about your code.

Comment: This can also allow you to change fonts as well :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// My preferred way of accessing searchField

if let searchTextField = self.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField {

  searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

}
```

Comment: Is this a private interface?

Comment: Nope... The search text field is not exposed formally on the search bar but is accessible via KVO.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).textColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case for swift 3.0

(mySearchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField)?.textColor = UIColor.white

Answer (score 0):

```
searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white
```