# search bar tint color

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar, tint

In my app I have set a searcher like this:

```
searchBar.delegate = self
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
searchBar.spellCheckingType = .No
searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .None
searchBar.autocorrectionType = .No
searchBar.returnKeyType = .Done
searchBar.sizeToFit()

let view: UIView = self.searchBar.subviews[0] as UIView
   for subView: UIView in view.subviews {
      if subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
         subView.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
         }
      }
```

this code part set an white text color for my cancel button and a green color for my search field.

as you can see, the cursor will be green, but the text color is black.
what is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: i would like to change the text color to green

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284658/searchbar-how-to-change-text-color

Comment: see this also it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499701/how-can-i-change-the-uisearchbar-search-text-color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where you have:

```
 if subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
      subView.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
 }
```

Change to:

```
 if let textView = subView as? UITextField {
      textView.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
      textView.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for swift is:

```
let searchField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
searchField.tintColor = orangeColor
```

Comment: I am not going to criticise anyone to giving me a downvote. If you found something wrong then it's rightful to do. I just want to request that, please do not downvote only but also mention the reason in comment. So, he/she would not repeat the same mistake again. Thanks